# Conditional formatting using DAX for text values containing specific substring

Tags: powerbi, dax, conditional-formatting

on power bi I created an object of table type. I need to color the cell of some specific columns depending the kind of text they contain. For  example, if some cells contains the substring (G) I have to apply the green background color to those cells. If a cell contains contains the substring (Y), then it must be yellow and so on. I also need a rule to apply blue color to all non null values.
Until now I've used conditional formatting based on rules, manually creating each rule for each column, but I'd like to create a measure in order to apply all this changes to more columns at once. It would be also grate a measure for each column, at least to avoid to manually create each rule. I made a try, but it didn't work.

I created this measure and then I used it as field in conditional formatting based of field values.

```
ColorValues = 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    CONTAINS('Result_check_(previous)','Result_check_(previous)'[Software Code Version (F195)], "(G)"), "#67F465",
    CONTAINS('Result_check_(previous)','Result_check_(previous)'[Software Code Version (F195)], "(Y)"), "#F8FF65",
    CONTAINS('Result_check_(previous)','Result_check_(previous)'[Software Code Version (F195)], "(R)"), "#EC2F2F",
    CONTAINS('Result_check_(previous)','Result_check_(previous)'[Software Code Version (F195)], "####"), "#FFFFFF",
    BLANK()
)
```

I also tried to use the CONTAINSSTRING function, but in this way no column name is recognized.

Can someone help me please?